# GridView bottom view

Tags: android, gridview

Можем ли мы добавить View под GridView? Именно после последнего элемета
как тут:
[image]

т.е Loading этот не статичен и если мы листнем вверх он останется на месте, он находится за последним элементом в GridView

Comment: тоже интересует данная тема, ибо у GridView нет такого свойства, как у ListView. для ListView можно задать FooterView, он и будет выполнять необходимую функцию. Наверняка есть готовые решения, но я что-то никак ничего не могу найти

Comment: Да вот тоже не могу найти.

Comment: так может все же вам нужен pull-to-refresh, только не для реализации ListView.
Вот в этой либе есть и ScrollView, а в него вы можете поместить все что угодно :)
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: нет, пул ту рефреш не нужен, нужен GridView с FooterView

Comment: тогда самый тупой способ в лоб, это добавить в ListView как header GridView, а в footer уже то, что вам надо :)

Comment: хм, интересная идея)
сегодня на работе попробую

Answer (score 2):

Надо поместить ваш `GridView` в `RelativeLayout` и там применить атрибут [android:layoutAlignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentBottom)

**Update**
Схематично как-то так:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <GridView/>
    <MyView android:layoutAlignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Тогда `MyView` будет внизу

Comment: ну и кнопка(или другой видимый элемент) будет под GridView но она будет постоянно видимой

Comment: этот прием называется push-to-refresh, погугли примеры

Comment: мб pull to refresh? нет, это совсем не то

Comment: при каких условиях он (лоадер) должен появляться? его можно поставит там и сделать visible.gone, а когда надо отображать

Comment: Visible и Gone тоже не покатят. Невозможно отследить. Сетка с очень большими элементами

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал много разных способов, в том числе и как предложили в комментариях: запихнуть **GridView** в хидер **Listview**, а лоадер в футер. В итоге все пришло к тому, что я написал свой **GridView** наследованием от **ListView**, зато теперь есть хидер и футер.

Comment: Если бы вы еще и код выложили, то было бы просто супер)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать так:

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```