# Как правильно переставить элемент?

Tags: android

Имеется 1:

[image]

Имеется 2:

[image]

Надо:

[image]

Вопрос: как?

p.s. Разумеется должно работать на всех размерах экрана

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пора уже FAQ делать из этого.

[Тынц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/214906/android-gridview-bottom-view)

Comment: Так в этом случае элемент будет у самого низа, а мне надо, чтобы был какой-нибудь отступ

Comment: а для чего существуют поля marign и padding